# warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*''

Tags: c++, c

I have declared the string array in my code as follows.

```
char *arr[] ={ 
"xyz",
"abc",
"pqr",
NULL
};
```

When compile then got following warning

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*''
```

i know that "xyz" and other string literal are const char and my array is char* so have resolve it by declaring my array const char* arr but i loss the control to point this array in another pointer.
So to resolve above issue have declared array as follows

```
 char *arr[] ={ 
    (char *)"xyz",
    (char *)"abc",
    (char *)"pqr",
    NULL
    };
```

But this type of declaration not fair when need large array (more then 100 string array).
So any one have idea to resolve it by another way.

Comment: You have tagged this C++ (which is not the same language as C), so why not use a `std::vector` of `std::string`s?

Comment: The error message comes from a C++ compiler: this is valid in C but not in C++.

Comment: yes std:string is perfectly valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't lose any re-pointing options by making the array a `const char* arr[]`. Note that there's a huge difference between `const char * p` (a mutable pointer to an immutable `char`) and a `char * const p` (an immutable pointer to a mutable `char`). This code is perfectly valid:

```
const char *arr[] = {
  "xyz",
  "abc",
  "pqr",
  NULL
};

arr[1] = "ghi";
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/WFUtls)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a `const char*` and `char *const` if your pointer is a `const char*` you can still point it to another location but you cannot modify the elements it contains. The correct solution in this case is to make the array `const char*`.

Comment: I think you mean `char * const` for the second one.

Comment: no requirements for modifying it but require to traverse it by pointing it to another pointer. Have also tried it by declaring const char* but it cause the error at line where i assign address of above array to another pointer.

Comment: @user3150853 is the pointer you assign to of another type? For instance if you try to point this array to an array of type `char * []` you will not succeed.

Comment: for example have assign above array to another char pointer  like char *pp = arr.

Comment: You can not assign a `char*` to a `const char*[]` these are two completely different types. It's like trying to assign an integer to an array of integers: `int a[2]; int b = a;` and of course this will never compile.

Comment: @jayeshbhoi You can type `const char* pp = arr;`. That should work.

Comment: @rozina You mean `const char* pp = arr[some_index];`, right?

Comment: @Angew Yes I do :) Actually I didn't think it through. Thanks for correcting the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

String literals are constant, so you need `const` pointers to refer to them:

```
const char *arr[] = {
    // whatever
};
```

Historically, it used to be possible (but dangerous) to convert string literals to non-const `char*`, for compatibility with ancient code that didn't know about `const`. This conversion has been deprecated for many years, and finally removed from the language in 2011.

Comment: I don't think this post addresses the question OP apparently knows about `const char*` and literals but has problems using this type.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: If that is the case, the solution will depend very much on why there are "problems" with `const char*`; and should probably be solved by addressing those "problems", not by subverting the type system.

Comment: I agree. The question does not contain enough information to give a complete answer.